# Jquery to display a JSON data in a web page

Tags: jquery

I have to display a JSON data in a web page on button click

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:10px;">
      <div id="testResult" style="padding-left: 120px; display: none; ">
        <img src="./images/spinner.gif" />Running the test...
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It s the html data am using

Bellow is the code written in the button click

```
    $('#runBtn').click(function() {
         $.get('/getReport', function (data) {
alert(data) // prints [{ "id" : 16, "jobid" : "49", "status" : "Falied" }]
        $('#testResult').html(data);
        });
    }
```

But nothing is showing in the web page

Comment: Isn't your `testResult` element hidden? `<div id="testResult" style="... display: none; ">`

Comment: I assume that's not *all* of your HTML, since there's no element with an ID of `runBtn` in there.

Comment: Since `alert()` doesn't print `[object Object]` this means that jQuery doesn't parse the response, you should either parse the JSON yourself using `JSON.parse()` or pass the `dataType` as the third argument to `$.get(url, fn, 'json')` function.

Comment: @BlackSheep Or use `jQuery.getJSON()`. If they parse it from a string to an array, however, they can't just pass that directly to `.html()` - jQuery has no idea what to do with that (it just seems to fail silently).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, `.html()` doesn't do anything with that array, I assumed setting the JSON response as innerHTML of an element is not the OP's final goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with the id "testResult" is hidden. Change your Jquery to the following example, to make it visible.

```
$('#runBtn').click(function() {
    $.get('/getReport', function (data) {
        alert(data) // prints [{ "id" : 16, "jobid" : "49", "status" : "Falied" }]
        $('#testResult').html(data).show();
    });
}
```

I made an example on jsfiddle. Try it here: [jsfiddle.net/ph3nx/F6uAn/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/ph3nx/F6uAn/4/)

Comment: Or chain the functions: `$('#testResult').html(data).show();`

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to loop the data for getting each items from json object:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  alert(index + ': ' + value.Name);
});
```

Comment: It's never actually parsed so it's just a string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The 'display: none' part of your html div (with id 'testResult') prevents this div from showing. You should change/remove it.